# refer to section 10.4.4.1 "copying object" of TC++PL  3rd edition

Tags: c++

`class table{
  name *p;      int i;

   public:

   table(int j=15){p=new name[i=j]}  //constructor

 ~table(){delete[]p;}
}`

```
 void h()     
{
    table t1;  
    table t2=t1; 
    table t3;  
    t3=t2;
}`
```

Bjarne wrote array created for `t1` will be deleted 3 times as array created for `t1` appears in `t1`,`t2`,`t3`**

Can you please explain what does this mean with some other examples.

Comment: Please provide more context for the example. What is definition of type `table`? It is impossible to answer this question without knowing, How copy constructor and copy assignment operator of `table` are implemented.

Comment: There are different editions of C++PL with considerable differences. Also not everyone owns a copy. Therefore it's really a good idea to post all relevant information here (especially the definition of `table`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the copy constructor and operator = only copy the value of a pointer, in the end t1, t2 and t3 will have pointers to the same bit of memory. If table has a destructor that deletes the pointer, the same pointer will be deleted three times - once for every object. This should cause a segfault.

To prevent this a class can allocate a new array for every copy (called making a [deep copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Deep_copy)), or do [reference counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting).