# refer to section 10.4.6.3 "copying members" of TC++PL 3rd edition

Tags: c++

What does this statement mean?

> A default copy constructor or default copy assignment copies all
>   elements of of the class. If this copy cannot be done, it is an error
>   to try to copy an object of class.

For example:

```
class unique_handle{    
    unique_handle(const unique_handle&);
    unique_handle&operator=(const unique_handle&);  
public ://...
};  

struct Y {
    unique_handle a;
}//require explicit initialization  
Y y1;
Y y2=y1; //error:cannot copy Y::a
```

Comment: Please learn how to indent code properly

Comment: [Seems like you need a helpdesk.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8890711/500104) SO isn't one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A default copy constructor or default copy assignment copies all elements of of the class.

"Default" here is an unconventional way of saying "implicitly defined".

Since the class `Y` doesn't declare a copy constructor (i.e. a constructor `Y(Y&)` or `Y(Y const &)`), then one is *implicitly declared*. When you try to use it, it is *implicitly defined* to copy all the base-class objects and members of `Y` (just a single member in this case), as if you'd written something like:

```
Y::Y(Y const &other) : a(other.a) {}
```

> If this copy cannot be done, it is an error to try to copy an object of class.

However, this constructor can only be defined if all the members can be copied. In this case `unique_handle` has a private copy constructor, which can't be called from this constructor.

Similarly, since `Y` doesn't declare a copy-assignment operator (i.e. `operator=(Y&)` or `operator=(Y const&)`), then one is again implicitly declared. If you tried to use it, then it would be implicilty defined to assign all the members, as if you'd written:

```
Y & Y::operator=(Y const & other) {
    a = other.a;
    return *this;
}
```

which again would fail, since `unique_handle` has a private copy-assignment operator.

Answer (score 2):

If your class contains an element that cannot be copied (`unique_handle` has a private copy-constructor, so it can indeed not be copied), then an element-wise copy is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

`class` members are `private` by default, `struct` members are `public` by default.

Because you didn't specify an access modifier to the constructors in your class, they are private, and therefore inaccessible from the outside.